# How can I generate random number in range?

Tags: java, android, random, numbers

I have 2 `EditText`. The user will enter the minimum number in the first `EditText` and the maximum in the second `EditText`.

There is one `TextView` to show  the generated number and a `Button` to click after entering the minimum and maximum numbers

How to generate a number between 2 numbers the user entered and show it in `TextView` ?

Answer (score 4):

Create a random number in the interval `[0, max - min]`, and add `min` to it.

```
Random r = new Random();
int number = min + r.nextInt(max-min+1); //add +1 because nextInt generate in the half-open range [0, n).
```

For example if `min = 10` and `max = 20` :

1. `r.nextInt(20-10+1)` will generate a random number between 0 and 10
2. You add 10 to this number
3. You get a random number in the range [10 - 20]

Check the [`Random`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html) class.

To show it in your `TextView`, use `String.valueOf` :

```
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```

Comment: I got it working but how can I set up min value as EditText1 and max as EditText2 ?

Comment: @user3182651 See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-any-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android