# How to fix minimum and maximum value in double value for Edit Text in android?

Tags: java, android

I have refered this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-any-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android)

to set minimum and maximum value for edit text to allow to enter. But i want to fix minimum and maximum value as double value. Minimum value should allow to enter starting from 0.25 and maximum value should allow 1000.0. How to fix it?

Comment: why u dot try DigitsKeyListener

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package com.test;

import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private double min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(double min, double max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Double.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Double.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, double start, double end, Spanned dest, double dstart, double dend) {
        try {
            double input = Double.parseDouble(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(double a, double b, double c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because InputFilter.filter() only accepts ints.

[Found in docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)

Comment: This solution is only for mins and maxes that are integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use input filter. Here is my solution

```
public class MinMaxInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    private double mMinValue;
    private double mMaxValue;

    private static final double MIN_VALUE_DEFAULT = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    private static final double MAX_VALUE_DEFAULT = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    public MinMaxInputFilter(Double min, Double max) {
    this.mMinValue = (min != null ? min : MIN_VALUE_DEFAULT);
    this.mMaxValue = (max != null ? max : MAX_VALUE_DEFAULT);
    }

    public MinMaxInputFilter(Integer min, Integer max) {
    this.mMinValue = (min != null ? min : MIN_VALUE_DEFAULT);
    this.mMaxValue = (max != null ? max : MAX_VALUE_DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        String replacement = source.subSequence(start, end).toString();
        String newVal = dest.subSequence(0, dstart).toString() + replacement
            + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length()).toString();

        // check if there are leading zeros
        if (newVal.matches("0\\d+.*"))
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(source))
            return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
        else
            return "";

        // check range
        double input = Double.parseDouble(newVal);
        if (!isInRange(mMinValue, mMaxValue, input))
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(source))
            return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
        else
            return "";

        return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        LOGE("inputfilter", "parse");
    }
    return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(double a, double b, double c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
   editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

   InputFilter limitFilter = new MinMaxInputFilter(mMinValue, mMaxValue);
   editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { limitFilter });
```

Comment: This will prevent a user from typing anything at all.
The only way this works is that the user pastes the value in an EditText.

Comment: @manishKungwani this works just fine for us for about 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to define the `EditText.setOnFocusChangedListener` :

```
public abstract void onFocusChange (View v, boolean hasFocus){
   if(v.getId() == (yourEditTextID) && hasFocus == false){
           //Check your editTextValue
           //if not in range, show an error (Toast ?) and refocus
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Too late but works very well:

```
package com.test;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
/**
 * Created by Admin on 22.04.2016.
 */
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
            double input = Double.valueOf(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, double c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(id.editText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("0", "100")});
```

Comment: This solution is only for mins and maxes that are integers.