# EditText length with "exceptions"

Tags: android, android-edittext, maxlength, android-input-filter

I have an EditText and I'd like to set maxLength to four numbers (in range -9999 to 9999). Problem is that if I set`android:maxLength="4"` in xml I can write there e.q "9999" but it doesn't accept "-9999" because of length (5 char). Is there any opportunity how to solve it (programatically or anyhow)

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29248270/4706693

Comment: use it as last resort.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-any-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android

Comment: I think you have to check it in run time...if user enter negative values then upgrade the maxlength to 5

Comment: Thank you. However, solution with max value doesn't work for float, because of integers.