# How to Restrict the value of EditText Max 15

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want the user cannot enter greater than value 15. If the user enters the value 1 and then enter 6 that time 6 must not be entered. Only below 15 values can enter a user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in XML to allow numbers only in Edit Text:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text_id"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="numbers" />
```

To control the text values entered in that EditText:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
    String strEnteredVal = edittext.getText().toString();

    if(!strEnteredVal.equals("")){
    int num=Integer.parseInt(strEnteredVal);
    if(num<16){
     edittext.setText(""+num);
    }else{
     edittext.setText("");
    }
}

});
```