# How can I restrict my edittext to allow 0-125 to be entered, without allowing anything >125 to be entered?

Tags: android

Here is the code I'm trying :

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {

            String strEnteredVal = edtMaxAge.getText().toString();

            if(!strEnteredVal.equals("")) {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(strEnteredVal);
                if (num < 125) {
                    edtMaxAge.setText(num);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "max age should be less than 125 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edtMaxAge.setText("");
                }
            }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
```

When I enter a number >= 125 I need to show a popup message, like "max age should be less than 125", without accepting the characters.

Comment: whats the error you are facing.?

Comment: Use InputFilter

Comment: in this case  my app crashes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

try {

          if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editable) {
                initial = editable.toString();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(initial);
                if (num < 125) {
                    edtMaxAge.setText(num);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "max age should be less 
                 than 125 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edtMaxAge.setText("");
                    return;
                }
            }

} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are facing a kind of endless recursion, when you enter some text `onTextChanged` method is invoked and it executes this line `edtMaxAge.setText(num);` which triggers `onTextChanged` again.

Try to use [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) instead of TextWatcher. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android) you can find an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use InputFilter.
It gives a lot of choices to filter your input such as capital letters, numbers within certain limit etc.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android) is the exact answer what you need