# Range EditText validation

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to validate my edittext for my number that is range between 100 and 200.So according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android) i have created `InputFilterMinMax` class.When i am running my app, i can not write anything into my edittext because when i insert 1 in `InputFilterMinMax` class `return ""`. I want to insert 100 into my edittext.

This is edittext xml :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtTajavozArea"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

After initialized my ui i have created a method for ui validation because some validation comes from my server and i have to apply on my android ui. Then im oncreate method i have:

```
LoadUi();
validateForm();
LoadObj();
```

Into `validateForm` method i have this part of code :

```
String viewIdName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ControlName"));
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(viewIdName, "id", this.getPackageName());
View view = findViewById(id);
if (view instanceof EditText) {

if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MaxValue")).equals("null") &&
        !cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MinValue")).equals("null")) {
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MaxValue"))),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MinValue"))))});
}
```

As you can see i get my view in this way because my view once loaded into `LoadUi()` method.

But as i mention above i can not write anything!!

This is InputFilterMinMax class:

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet

```
if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MaxValue")).equals("null") &&
        !cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MinValue")).equals("null")) {
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MaxValue"))),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MinValue"))))});
}
```

You are going from MaxValue to MinValue so the MinValue and the MaxValue just needs to be swapped. It should be

```
if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MaxValue")).equals("null") &&
        !cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MinValue")).equals("null")) {
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MinValue"))),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MaxValue"))))});
}
```

Comment: Sort is important? @Isaiahj

Comment: Yes, order is important because your input filter accepts the parameters InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) so MinValue should go first.

Comment: I can not insert anything into my edittext, again. because when i insert 1 , 1 is not range between 100 and 200 and 1 is not register into edittext   @ IsaiahJ

Comment: And again when i insert next number, this number is first and absolutely this number is between 100 and 200 @ IsaiahJ

Comment: I see. If you check the comments on your [source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212734/6902410), it seems that the InputFilterMinMax really doesn't work for ranges like 100 to 200.

Comment: Then this is not useful code.. it seems like the number must be start from 1 :-( @IsaiahJ

Comment: Yes unfortunately. I'd suggest using a Spinner instead or just validating the EditText upon form submission.