# Set Edit Text input between set min and max

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` that will put this sets of value

`58.44`,`44.2` or even negative like `-58.44`,`-44.2`

how can I prevent it from surpassing between -100 and 100 i tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android) but no joy.

I wanna make my `EditText` to type between -100 and 100 only if surpasses then dont continue typing.

Comment: please show example how you want it to work. `but no joy` it is not expected to bring you joy.

Comment: edited my post sir

Comment: It would be easier to add TextWatcher and handle the entered text in onTextChanged()

Comment: this is not a task for an EditText. You should use a SeekBar for this. But if you want - add a textWatcher, which will check the text entered each time it changes, and restore previous text if current one does not fit your requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can add the condition like this

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                String value = s.toString();
                Double numericValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
                if (numericValue < -100 || numericValue > 100) {
                    editText.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Set your EditText inputType as

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

Comment: tried typing but nothing shows and after i input a "-" an error occurs `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"`

Comment: Please handle NumberFormatException, it happens while calling parseDouble method.

The remaining logic is if you enter any number > 100 or < -100 it would reset the EditText to blank

Comment: i add a try and catch but nothing shows when i type

Comment: That is strange, the entered text should appear unless it is out the of the range.

Comment: even i just used the condition then shows some message if it not falls between but after inputing the right value it always says it is not between 100

Comment: The condition definitely works. It is just (-100 <= x <= 100). I am not sure why you cannot see entered text. I did not implement the code, but I am positive that it works. I will check and update in case there is any issue.

Comment: Hi, I just tried my above answer. I can absolutely see entered text. I just edited the login removing = to accept 100 and -100 as well. If it is not working for, it would help if you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve programmatically, `TextWatcher` is a good option.

Inside `onTextChanged()`, Check if your changed CharSequence s, matches you need, otherwise replace it.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});
```

Comment: this one is ok but how can I achieve the condition

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex pattern  you can handle the numbers between `-99.99` and `99.99`

> ^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}+$

**Update 2:**
For >=-100 and <=100, use this regex:

> ^[-+]100|^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}+$

Below sample, checks the text and enables/disables the button if matches or not.

```
EditText mEditText;
Button mButton;
final static String mRegex = "^[-+]100|^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}+$";
boolean inputMatches;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mEditText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new InputController());

    mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setEnabled(inputMatches);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," Input matches!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public class InputController implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String input = mEditText.getText().toString();
        inputMatches = input.matches(mRegex);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As per your request on clearing `Edittext`.. There are multiple ways to do it. You can either follow other answers above or you can use my above answer if it fits with you and instead using `TextWatches`, you can use `OnFocusChangeListener`. This is better if you have multiple Edittexts. When your one `Edittext` loses focus, then this code will trigger to see if it matches the regex pattern. If no match, clears it.
Remove above TextWatcher, follow bellow:

1. Implement `OnFocusChangeListener` in your `Activity`

   ```
   MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener
   ```
2. Override its `onFocusChange` method.

   ```
   @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {}
   ```
3. Inside `onFocusChange` do your checks.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
       if(!b){ // Lost focus
           String text = ((EditText)view).getText().toString();
           if(text.matches(mRegex)){
               // It matches
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Input matches!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else{
               // No match - clear Edittext
               ((EditText)view).setText("");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Input doesn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Update 2**

To include -100 and 100, use this regex pattern:

> ^[-+]100|^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}+$

Comment: can you make the edittext that it will delete the input if it doesnt neet the condition

Comment: true or false i see

Comment: there are chances that the user will input 100 so need to consider that

Comment: Check my latest update. With the new regex pattern I wrote, you can include -100 and 100 as well.