# Restrict input in pair of EditText by applying InputFilters on-the-fly

Tags: java, android, validation, user-interface

**INTRODUCTION**:

I am having some trouble enforcing validation to a pair of `EditText` values in an Android project. The language is Java. `android:inputType="number"` is set. Both views are empty, by default.

For example, the validation rule is that `editTextA` and `editTextB` cannot both be zero. Ideally, the validation should be performed when the user finishes input in either view.

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

Here's another example. Values of `editTextA` and `editTextB` should sum up to 5 max.

Using `TextWatcher` seems to work okay but it's far from perfect. I think the best way would be to somehow be able to restrict user input on one control based on the current value of the other. Let's say that `onCreate` contains the following code:

```java
editTextA.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("0", "5")});
editTextB.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("0", "5")});
```

where `InputFilterMinMax` is a class that implements `InputFilter` as per [Is there a way to define a min and max value for EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android/14212734#14212734)

Now let's assume value of `editTextA` becomes 3. The max filter value of `editTextB` should now be 2 instead of 5.

The question is can this be applied on-the-fly?

**PART OF ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

*Problem 1:* I tried to set a `EditorActionListener` but there are just too may ways a control can lose focus and I can't get the validation code to work on all cases. I've tried:

```java
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || actionId = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_PREVIOUS) {
    // get values of A and B
    return (valueA+valueB>0);
}
return false;
```

but doesn't seem to work when the user clicks directly on another control, for example.

*Problem 2:* The above approach doesn't seem to work in a consistent way especially when I am trying to set an error, too. Where the `setError()` should be called in the action listener?

Overall, the above approach seems clumsy. Is there any other way to perform such validation?

Comment: Did you try to use addTextChangedListener() ?

Comment: @FedeFonto That's much better even though far from perfect. I wonder if InputFilter can be set on-the-fly based on each other's value. But that's another question probably. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @FedeFonto I've decided to update the original question.

Comment: Have you tried onFocusChangeListener in combination with TextWatcher to re-set the input filter to the other fields?

Comment: @FedeFonto Haven't tried that. Is it too much to ask you for a code sample?