# What's the best way to limit EditText number value in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, input, android-edittext

What's the best way to limit EditText value in Android studio? I want people can input numbers from 1-10 not zero, not 11 or other. I want only from 1 to 10 number value can input in edit text. if people input more then 10 then how can I control this in java?

Comment: visite this link >> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android)

Comment: @FelipePalma thank you so much its works