# How We define range between min and max custom value like 85 and 110 for EditText in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i have requirement restrict Edit Text that input type is number. i need only accept value >= 85 and value <=110 . please help. i search a lot but many people gives solution from value 1 to some limit.

Comment: Put TextWatcher listener on EditText and you can do two things here. Either replace the text with your desire limited range or just show the error to user

Comment: Why not use a SeekBar instead? You can set min and max values on the SeekBar and have it update the value in a TextView to show them what they're selecting. That's much more user friendly than trying to limit a number as it's being typed. How can you stop them from typing 11 without stopping them from typing 110?

Comment: dear i have edittext that take human temperature  like its allow only value between 85 to 110.. seekbar is not an option in my case.

Comment: Why does that prevent you from using SeekBar? Spinner might be another good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Please make one class like this..

```
class FilterInput:InputFilter {
  private val min:Int = 0
  private val max:Int = 0
  constructor(min:Int, max:Int) {
    this.min = min
    this.max = max
  }
  constructor(min:String, max:String) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min)
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max)
  }

}
```

now you can use this class in your Ui(Activity/Fragment)..

```
etInput.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(FilterInput("85", "110"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to this answer: [Is there a way to define a min and max value for EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android)

Best solution is, as also already answered by Jaimil, the `InputFilter`. But additionally to his answer, **you have to override the `filter()` method** in your custom class. Like this:

```
package com.test;

import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("85", "1")});
```

E viola!

Comment: Won't this prevent you from typing anything? When you type the first digit, I would expect it to be interpreted as a one-digit number the first time `filter` is called, and it won't be bigger than 85 so it will be rejected.

Comment: As you can read here in the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter the filter method is not called instantly but first everything will be written in a buffer and as soon as the buffer will be cleared and the text will be processed the filter method will be called.

Comment: this will not fulfill my requirement.. because it will work BTW start from 1 to unlimited... but when you set 85 is start point try to type 7 in edit text 7 is less then 85 . we are unable to type in edit input even not allow 8 ,9 etc

Comment: The buffer is cleared every time you type a character. The only reason there is a buffer is to handle copy-paste and auto-complete, where multiple characters can be put in the buffer at once.